# WPF Toolkit PropertyGrid Style

Tags: wpf, propertygrid, toolkit

i am trying to override the wpf toolkit propertygrid's style. Therefore i modified the generic.xaml. 
Now i have the problem that the defaulteditors styles are not overridden. 
Therefore i wrote following style to override the PropertyGridEditorComboBox in Xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:PropertyGridEditorComboBox}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Value}" ItemsSource="{?????}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

This snippet seems to work except the fact that i do not know what i have to bind as an itemssource. What do i have to bind as Itemssource?

If there is also a better way to override the DefaultEditors appearance please let me know.

KR Manuel

Answer (score 0):

You have to reach from the style to the control it's applied to -- something like this:

```
ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
```

(Assuming that `PropertyGridEditorComboBox` has an `ItemsSource` property.)